# Relative Chow's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose you have a smooth quasiprojective complex algebraic variety that is not compact. Suppose you have a complex analytic fiber bundle over the algebraic variety where each fiber is a smooth projective variety. Is the bundle itself algebraic? If not, what are some extra conditions we can impose to deduce that the bundle is algebraic?

I guess this is pretty standard but I couldn't find anything useful from a quick search.

Comment: The Hopf surface is an analytic fiber bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$, with fiber an elliptic curve. Just take out a point in $\mathbb{P}^1$ if you don't want a compact base.